# Moving passport AUTH route handler to controller not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I would like to move the passport logic to a controller (in another file). First example is working, but in example below the `googleCallback` in `authController` isn't working, I can't figure out where's the error. Thanks in advance.

```js
app.get('/auth/google', 
  passport.authenticate('google', { session: false, scope: ['email', 'profile'] })
)

app.get('/auth/google/callback',
  passport.authenticate('google', { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    res.send({ loggedUser: req.user.displayName })
  }
)
```

```js
app.get('/auth/google', authController.googleAuth)
app.get('/auth/google/callback', authController.googleCallback)

authController = {

  googleAuth: passport.authenticate('google', { session: false, scope: ['email', 'profile'] }),

  googleCallback: (
    passport.authenticate('google', { session: false }),
    (req, res) => {
      res.send({ loggedUser: req.user.displayName })
    }
  )
  
}
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? How do you know it isn't working?

Comment: @zr0gravity7 googleAuth triggers the google auth view, that's working, but when i select my email account it would redirect to googleCalback (is not working).